# Possible inconsistency for the Unicode data associated with the Chinese character U+5F8C 後

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, cjk

[Here](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=5f8c) you'll find the following data for the Chinese Unicode character U+5F8C 後 :

> kGB0 = 6565 (kuten form for the simplified character 後)
>
> kGB1 = 2683
>
> kSimplifiedVariant = U+540E 后

How can the simplified form for the character U+58FC be equal to the character 6565 (which is the character 後) and at the same time have kSimplifiedVariant = U+540E ?

Comment: You are mixing Unicode encodings with legacy non-Unicode encodings.  Note the missing U in front of the legacy encoding values.

Answer (score 2):

The kGB0 and kGB1 mappings only specify the code numbers of the character in other character codes. The number 6565 is simply the code number of U+5F8C in GB 2312-80.

The kSimplifiedVariant mapping, on the other hand, maps one Unicode character to another, as described in clause [3.7.1 Simplified and Traditional Chinese Variants](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/index.html#SCTC) of UAX #38. The characters U+5F8C and U+540E are distinct code points, but the mapping defines a correspondence between them. The correspondence as such has no implications. It just means that you can perform certain conversions, such as replacing CJK characters by their Simplified Chinese forms.

Comment: The problem that I see here is that GB 2312-80 is the standard for the PRC simplified characters. What does it mean to have the character 後 listed in GB 21312-80, if it is not the simplified character for the character 後 in GB 12345-90.

Comment: If Unicode data is converted to GB 21312-80, then U+5F8C is mapped to 6565. Character U+540E has the same mapping, because U+540E is a variant of U+5F8C. From the Unicode viewpoint, simplified and traditional characters are variants, though in many cases, the variants are also separately encoded in Unicode. But when Unicode data is converted to a character code that does not make such distinction but has only traditional or only simplified characters, the distinction is just lost.